# VSCode keybinding to hide Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keybinding in VSCode that can hide Explorer, like <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> works for showing it?

I hate reaching for the mouse and I don't have enough screen space to keep Explorer always on.

Answer (score 350, accepted):

Toggle Sidebar Visibility: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

If you're a MacOS user, then it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.

[Visual Studio Code Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_display)

Comment: I had to resign shortcut priorities, because on my Mac CMD-b was assigned also to "Navigate Next in Quick Open".

Comment: I had Vscodevim hijack the ``Ctrl + /`` on the first installment. In case anyone's wondering about the actual ``keybinds.json`` name, it's ``workbench.action.toggleSidebar``.

Comment: It didn't work in my case as ctrl+b was assigned to both workbench.action.toggleSidebar and some debug command (by default, I didn't change anything). Editing the workbench.action.toggleSidebar shortcut and pressing ctrl+b will show you if you have such duplicates and so you can delete/change the conflicting keybindings on a case by case basis.

Comment: I would say, `Shift+B` is better choice for  `workbench.action.toggleSidebar` if there is a vim plugin using `Ctrl+B`

Comment: Maybe in the future the sidebar could be easier to hide/show if it had a little tab or made itself known when mouse is on the left edge of the application screen.

CTRL+B and similar is is not easily remembered if you work with 65 other amazing IDE;s the same day.

Eclipse already occupies half of my flash memory brain cells.

Comment: Ctrl+B works on Windows

Answer (score 55):

If you're a MacOS user, then it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>.

I won't leave you without a GIF.

[image: shortcut for mac VS Code]

Comment: Not sure why you didn't just edit the correct answer from a year earlier. So I did it instead.

Answer (score 28):

Some clarification: usually `Ctrl+B` is used for closing a sidebar (not toggling by default). So if you haven't a sidebar and want to open it - press the following combination: `Ctrl+Shift+E`(opens the sidebar with active explorer) or `Ctr+Shift+F` (with active search) etc. Now if you want to get rid of a sidebar press `Ctrl+B`. Note if you're using vim plugin and want to close a sidebar but currently is working on your code - first make a sidebar active by pressing (`Ctrl+Shift+E`) and then close it via `Ctrl+B`.

update: recently I've discovered that `Ctrl+Shift+E` doesn't play nice with my neo vim plugin, so in order to overcome it there is another shortcut to open sidebar explorer: single press of `Ctrl+0` to open it and pressing of `Ctrl+0` one more time to get focus on it.

Comment: This is what works for me when the editor pane is focussed. but that is a bit poop. If I am on the editor I just want to close the explorer for real estate not switch to explorer then hide it. Netbeans gives me CTRL + ESC from anywhere to hide the side bar.

Comment: I would expect the sidebar would close with the same shortcut that opens it... That's how Phpstorm does it, and it feels more natural.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use cmd+b to open and close your explorer add these lines to your keybindings.json

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+e",
        "command": "workbench.view.explorer"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+e",
        "command": "-workbench.view.explorer"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
        "when": "explorerViewletVisible"
    },
    {
        "key": "cmd+e",
        "command": "-workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
        "when": "explorerViewletVisible"
    },
```

Of course, you must replace the "e" with "b" !

Comment: ...and "cmd" with "ctrl"

Comment: Get to keybindings.json via:  ctrl-shift-p   -> keyboard shortcuts -> open keyboard.json

Comment: you're undoing both shortcuts (notice the minus, `-`, in two of the settings). `{"key": "cmd+b", "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"}` is all that should be needed, presuming `cmd+b` isn't colliding with another keybinding.

Answer (score 12):

VSCode default Keybinding for Toggling "Side Bar" aka "Explorer" is CTRL+B. 
Just CTRL+B alone works fine.

Comment: for me it does not work when the editor is focussed.  I have to do CTRL + SHIFT + E to focus the explorer and then CTRL + B really not impressed with this

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Visual Studio keymap.
On my keyboard shortcuts, *Toggle Side Bar Visibility* was set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> but doesn't works.

I do remap to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and works fine.

File > Preferences > KeyBoard ShortCuts

Answer (score 8):

This is an extension of @tsm's answer.

If you want to toggle `Explorer` using <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> then use the following keybindings.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInFilePicker",
    "when": "inFilesPicker && inQuickOpen"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+b",
    "command": "-workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.explorer' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.search'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.debug'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extensions' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.test'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.bookmarks'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.project-manager' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.gitlens'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.todo-tree-container'|| activeViewlet == 'snippet-explorer'"
}
```

Here, the first two keybindings are to unbind <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>. So, it depends on which commands you are currently using with <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>.

the third keybinding is to unbind <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> as you will no longer need <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to *Toggle Sidebar Visibility*.

The fourth keybinding is to view explorer using <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd>.

Now the interesting part. The fifth keybinding. Here, I am saying: "if sidebar is open and I press <kbd>Ctrl+E</kbd> then close the sidebar."

Please understand that, one of the way to open a `Sidebar` is to click one of the `Sidebar Icons`. When we click on a particular `Sidebar Icon`, we get it's corresponding `Sidebar View`.

To create this keybinding we have to get all the `Contexts` (in this case, value of `activeViewlet`) of each `Sidebar Views`.

How to get `Contexts` can be found on [VSCODE Accurate keybinding, want to know current context. How to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269534/vscode-accurate-keybinding-want-to-know-current-context-how-to-do). This same information can also be found on the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility).

So, long story short, I found the contexts by running `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` in command pallet and observing the `Developer Tools`.

1. Open VSCode debugger (click `Help > Toggle Developer Tools`).
2. Run `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` in command pallet
3. Open the sidebar you want to know the context (value of `activeViewlet`) of.
4. Get the context from the Developer Tool's Console.

Now, add these contexts (for example `workbench.view.explorer`, `workbench.view.search`, `workbench.view.scm` etc.) in the `when` key.

**Update 1:**

You actually do not need to find the contexts. You can just use:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "activeViewlet != ''"
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.explorer' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.search'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.debug'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extensions' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.test'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.bookmarks'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.project-manager' || activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.gitlens'|| activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.extension.todo-tree-container'|| activeViewlet == 'snippet-explorer'"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Mac, it's `cmd+B` and in windows, it's `ctrl+B`

Answer (score 4):

path (macos)

`~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/keybindings.json`

code

```
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+e", // toggle
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer", // show explorer
    "when": "!sideBarVisible" // apply when sidebar is hidden
},
{
    "key": "shift+cmd+e", // toggle
    "command": "workbench.action.closeSidebar", // close sidebar
    "when": "sideBarVisible" // apply when sidebar is visible
}
```

thx

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73970771/1347601

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was looking exactly that! I didn't want to to use cmd b to hide..

Answer (score 3):

Put this code into keybindings.json

```json
  { "key": "whatever_key_binding", "command": "workbench.files.action.showActiveFileInExplorer", "when": "!sideBarVisible" },
  { "key": "whatever_key_binding", "command": "workbench.action.closeSidebar", "when": "sideBarVisible" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Maicon Heck. On top of what he said, I change it to `Fn` + `B`. Since I'm using `vim` for visual studio code, and it kind of messing it with all the keyboard shortcut involving `Ctrl`.

Answer (score -2):

I have to say **`CTRL+B`** stands for calling out the sider bar.

To hide the sider bar, you should type: **`CTRl+\`**

Comment: I don't think your answer is right as ctrl + \ is used to split the editor