# VSCODE Accurate keybinding, want to know current context. How to do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Many of plugins can set their own specific "context" through the undocumented API *SetContext*. Since the documentation doesn't list these custom contexts, I can't just look into the documentation to know how to config my own keybinding in the right way. Is it possible to know the *current context* array?

For example: I would like to use keyboard shortcuts (no mouse) to navigate to the "git lens" panel (already have this), and then mark some files to stage by keyboard navigation, then invoke the commit editor, and just 'commit' my stuff.

Comment: Greetings, and wellcome to StackOverflow. Please review your post and improve it, because it does not comply to [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Run from command palette `Developer: Inspect Context Keys`
- Click on any SCM viewlet element
- Open Developer Tools `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools`

[image]

Comment: That was the piece I couldn't figure out.  Toggle developer tools.  Thanks for this!