# VSCode keybinding to view/hide Git tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any keybinding in VSCode that can view/hide Git tab?

I hate reaching for the mouse and I don't have enough screen space to keep Git always on.

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65816845, how i can do the same with Git?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found answer:

```
    {
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "workbench.view.scm"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "-workbench.view.scm"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+g",
    "command": "-workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility",
    "when": "activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
},
```